# Handling api call in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a api that needs to be called several times in 1 foreach loop and the way ive been doing it is defining the api url and parsing the info inside of the loop therefore its being called over and over until the loop ends, but im wondering if theres another way to handle something like this. For example if I have a api that gets info from states which is about 50 states and I put it in a foreach loop its going to loop all 50 times which will make the results load extremely slow, am I doing this correctly? how should I go about handling something like this if not?

Here is a example of how I am trying to use this.

```
//Theses are the states
  $z_state_abrev = zillow_state_abrev();  

//this is the foreach loop. 
  foreach($z_state_abrev as $states){
    $zillow_id = 'X1-ZWz1bp6dndxfd7_75222';
    $xml = file_get_contents('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetRateSummary.htm?zws-id='.$zillow_id.'&state='.$states.'');
    $zinfo_rates = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    foreach($zinfo_rates->response as $rates){
        dpr($rates->today->rate[0]);
        $zinfo_rates .= $rates->today->rate[0];
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where memcache is the best bet I can think of

http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

the results of your file_get_contents is stored into memcache and subsequent calls are pulled from the cache.  The first time its run it will be slow, but every time its called afterwards would be much faster.

It adds to your complexity a bit, but remember the second rule of web development, cache and cache often.

Comment: when you say the 1st time it runs it will be slow but everytime after it will be fast, do you mean it will be slow for all users that 1st run it and then fast the 2nd time around or will be it be slow just for the 1st initial load through out the site and then it will speed up after that for everyone?

Comment: Depends. If the data your gathering is scoped to the application as a whole, meaning all users see the same data, then the very first person in the system for the day will be a bit slow as the data is being recorded into the cache. But if the data is scoped per user, meaning each user gets different data, then the slowdown will be when they first come into the system as their data is being cached. But this can be managed in most cases

Answer (score 0):

If the API doesn't provide you a way to get multiple data in one request then you're out of luck.

To speed up the calls, however, look into [`curl_multi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) (or a request library that implements it) to make your calls in parallel rather than in serial.